# New-AzureRmADAppCredential : Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown

Tags: powershell, azure

I was trying to make a secret from PowerShell for a SPN and saw the following:
`New-AzureRmADAppCredential : Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown`.

Here is what I did to cause the bug and how to fix it.

1. created SPN: `New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName $adAppName -HomePage $adAppHomePage -IdentifierUris $adAppIdentifierUri -KeyCredentials $keyCredential`
2. created password from portal
3. tried to create a new password from PowerShell: `New-AzureRmADAppCredential -ObjectId 2222-3333-444 -Password 'wakatester'`
4. saw the following error: `New-AzureRmADAppCredential : Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.`
5. debugged and saw the following: "value": "Update to existing credential with KeyId '677dddaaa-4rde-bgt5-853a-2e02bce4c2f1' is not allowed."
6. to fix I deleted all secrets made from the portal
7. went back to PowerShell and created new certificates no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new password for an application, you need to remove all the credentials for an application for it. I test in my lab, it I don't remove credentials, I will get the same result with you. Please use the following commands to add a new password.

To remove all the credentials for an application, use:

```
Remove-AzureRmADAppCredential -ApplicationId 8bc80782-a916-47c8-a47e-4d76ed755275 -All
```

To add a password, use:

```
New-AzureRmADAppCredential -ApplicationId 8bc80782-a916-47c8-a47e-4d76ed755275 -Password p@ssword!
```

More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal).

Answer (score 2):

Use **-Debug** switch to see which parameter is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

The same cryptic error will be thrown if you have another application with same IdentifierUris